# rollapply for multidimensional arrays (R)

Tags: r, arrays, rollapply

*Not a duplicate of [rollapply for two-dimensional arrays (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511079/rollapply-for-two-dimensional-arrays-r), but rather an elaboration upon it - what I actually want to do is slightly more complicated than described in that question. I hoped that any answer to that question would easily extend to a solution for my actual problem, but that unfortunately proved not to be the case.*

For simple vectors we have

```
> a <- c(1:4)
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4
> rollapply(a, 2, mean)
[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5
```

which is as it should be. While `rollapply` itself is limited to one-dimensional vectors, several very helpful answers [such as this one by akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67511091/9231236) allowed me to extend this to two-dimensional arrays in a multitude of ways.

Unfortunately, I am now stuck again, because I do not see how any of the answers generalize to higher dimensions than two (*). Taking an array `b`

```
> b <- array(rep(c(1:4),each=6), c(2,3,4))
> b
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4
```

there should be some way to take means over a window-size of 2 to yield

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.5  1.5  1.5
[2,]  1.5  1.5  1.5

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  2.5  2.5  2.5
[2,]  2.5  2.5  2.5

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  3.5  3.5  3.5
[2,]  3.5  3.5  3.5
```

but I do not see how (obviously in real cases the sub-arrays would not consist of just repeating the same integer throughout the array, but would contain actual data).

Ideally, I would also like to be able to assign different weights to the various sub-arrays in the window for the purposes of the averaging, but I assume that would just be a matter of defining a custom function to apply.

(*) Perhaps there is an obvious way, but it's late where I am and I'm not finding it.

Comment: Do you need `apply(b, c(1,2), FUN = function(x) rollapply(x, 2, FUN = mean))`

Comment: I was confused that this doesn't seem to do what I'm asking for - but it does seem to work when combined with `aperm`!

Comment: Thanks again. As a plus, this whole escapade has lead to me *finally* discovering `aperm`. I knew that R had to have some equivalent of NumPy's `swapaxes`, but hadn't been able to find it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `zoo::rollapply` to work (as an external call, unlike its use internally in one of the comments), but one can mimic much of its behavior by controlling the input vector externally (`seq_len(dim(b)[3])[-1]`) and the "window" (`[-1]` externally, and `i-1:0` internally). From there, it's just a mean of one dim of an array:

```r
sapply(seq_len(dim(b)[3])[-1],
       function(i) apply(b[,,i-1:0,drop=FALSE], 1:2, mean),
       simplify="array")
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  1.5  1.5  1.5
# [2,]  1.5  1.5  1.5
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  2.5  2.5  2.5
# [2,]  2.5  2.5  2.5
# , , 3
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  3.5  3.5  3.5
# [2,]  3.5  3.5  3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `apply` is that it can do an implicit transpose of dimensions but `aaply` in the plyr package is similar but without the implicit transpose.

```
library(plyr)
library(zoo)

aaply(b, 1:2, rollmean, 2)
```

giving:

```
   X2
X1    1   2   3
  1 1.5 1.5 1.5
  2 1.5 1.5 1.5

, ,  = 2

   X2
X1    1   2   3
  1 2.5 2.5 2.5
  2 2.5 2.5 2.5

, ,  = 3

   X2
X1    1   2   3
  1 3.5 3.5 3.5
  2 3.5 3.5 3.5
```